# ExtJS/JS : DataView automatically scrolling up in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

In Internet Explorer(tested with IE11), the clicking on a dataview item will cause that item to automatically scroll to the top. To re-create the issue, paste the following code into ExtJS documentation [fiddle](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.view.View.html), run the fiddle, scroll all the way to bottom, and then click on one of the images. This will cause the dataview to scroll up automatically.

```
Ext.define('Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name:'src', type:'string' },
        { name:'caption', type:'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id:'imagesStore',
    model: 'Image',
    data: [
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-drawing.png', caption:'Drawing & Charts' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-data.png', caption:'Advanced Data' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png', caption:'Overhauled Theme' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-perf.png', caption:'Performance Tuned' }
    ]
});

var imageTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div class="abc">',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
              '<img src="{src}" />',
              '<br/><span>{caption}</span>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>'
);

Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
    tpl: imageTpl,
    itemSelector: 'div.abc',
    emptyText: 'No images available',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Is there any way I can stop this automatic scrolling ? This only happens in IE(the scroll position remains unaffected in FF and Chrome).

Comment: Have you tried by setting `focusable: false` config to the dataview ?

Comment: @RohitSharma yep, this did the trick!